# Как поменять несколько спрайтов между собой?

Tags: unity3d

Изучаю юнити и решил сделать механику похожую на кубик Рубика в 2d. Возникла проблема с изменением изображения спрайтов. Т.е. мне нужно неоднократно менять их между собой + в разных плоскостях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  Пример: из 123 получается 312, а после из 345 - 534 и т.д.

Просмотрел множество источников, но не нашел решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте объект Canvas, в качестве дочернего объекта создаем пустой объект и навешиваем на него компонент Grid Layout Group, настраиваем как в примере ниже. Далее создаем в качестве **дочерних** объектов нужное кол-во объектов с компонентов Image. Меняя их положение внутри родительского компонента - они будут менять своё положение в гриде (красный кубик имеет позицию [0,0], но если перенести его в самый конец списка, то его позиция изменится на [2,2]).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. И еще вопрос небольшой, а как к ним потом можно обратиться в скрипте? Для замены позиции при нажатии на кнопку